# How can I re-run a scaffold view create from a new template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

While the Rails scaffold system is a huge time-saver, I have found that a given site will have a different set of views, based on the particular framework. Up until recently I would manually edit each of the five view files {_form, edit, index, new, show} to suit the particular design, but this is getting old.

The ability to over-ride the default templates is an excellent new feature, and I now use that quite a bit. The problem is, I might have a lot of controllers and views, and if I need to redo the html in the view files after they have been created, I need to edit them all or use an elaborate 'sed' command.

I would prefer to be able to re-run the scaffold generator but just for the views. Something like:

```
$ rails g redo-views Post
```

This would recreate the five files from the new template, leaving the controller, model, migration and everything else, alone. The only alternative I can think of is to create a dummy site separately, and the manually copy the view files for each controller. This also requires that I know the parameters originally used during the scaffold generation, so it can create the right fields.

Is there a better/easier way?

Comment: do you mean want something like that `rails generate controller home index` that should generate only `index` action

Comment: I remembered doing something like `rails g erb:scaffold post title content`. You'd need to explicitly include all attributes however. It does not load the attributes automatically from the schema. I used a gem before that specifically handles this. It basically just prints out a string of all attributes of a model  as if you are generating a scaffold. From that I will just copy the string and paste it after  rails g erb.  I forgot the name  of the gem, I will update this should I remember.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rails g erb:scaffold post title content

However, you need to specify all attributes in this command.

A shortcut is to use [schema_to_scaffold](https://github.com/frenesim/schema_to_scaffold) which you could copy a string and append it to `rails g erb:scaffold` so that you will not need to manually include all attributes one by one

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
rails g erb:scaffold Post
```

Comment: Hi there. The problem is that this doesn't add all of the form attributes. Let's say I start with $ rails g scaffold Post title body:text author:references (and so on). If I want to redo the views, I'll need to re-run the entire command including all the field attributes. I'm wondering if there's an easier way.